# Python requests stops working mid-file

Tags: python, exception, web-scraping, python-requests

I've got a csv file with URL's and I need to scrape metadata from those website. I'm using python requests for that reasons with code below:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import html5lib
import sys
#import logging

filename = 'TestWTF.csv'
#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

#Get filename (with extension) from terminal
#filename = sys.argv[1]
tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
read_timeout = 1.0


#Does actual scraping done, returns metaTag data
def getMetadata (url, metaTag):
    r = requests.get("http://" + url, timeout=2)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
    metadata = soup.findAll(attrs={"name":metaTag})
    return metadata

#Gets either keyword or description
def addDescription ( row ):
    scrapedKeywordsData = getMetadata(row,  'keywords')
    if not scrapedKeywordsData:
        print row + ' NO KEYWORDS'
        scrapedKeywordsData = getMetadata(row,  'description')
        if not scrapedKeywordsData:
            return ''
    return scrapedKeywordsData[0]

def prepareString ( data ):
    output = data
    #Get rid of opening meta content
    if output.startswith( '<meta content="' ):
        output = data[15:]

    #Get rid of closing meta content (keywords)
    if output.endswith( '" name="keywords"/>' ):
        output = output[:-19]

    #Get rid of closing meta content (description)
    if output.endswith( '" name="description"/>' ):
        output = output[:-22]

    return output

def iterator():
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvFile, tempfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        writer = csv.writer(tempfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

        i = 0
        for row in reader:
            try:
                data = str(addDescription (row[1] ))
                row[3] = prepareString( data )
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print e
            except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
                print e
            except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout as e:
                print "lol"
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                print "These aren't the domains we're looking for."
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:
                print "Too slow Mojo!"



        writer.writerow(row)
        i = i + 1
        print i
    shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)

def main():
    iterator()


#Defining main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works just fine but at some URL's (out of 3000 let's say maybe 2-3) it would just suddenly stop working and not progress to next one after timeout time.. So I have to kill it using Ctr+C which results in file not being saved.

I know it's a problem of catching exceptions but I cannot figure out which one or what to do with that problem.. I'm more than happy to simply ignore the one which is stuck on..

EDIT:

Added traceback:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "blacklist.py", line 90, in <module>
    main()
  File "blacklist.py", line 85, in main
    iterator()
  File "blacklist.py", line 62, in iterator
    data = str(addDescription (row[1] ))
  File "blacklist.py", line 30, in addDescription
    scrapedKeywordsData = getMetadata(row,  'keywords')
  File "blacklist.py", line 25, in getMetadata
    metadata = soup.findAll(attrs={"name":metaTag})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1259, in find_all
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 537, in _find_all
    found = strainer.search(i)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1654, in search
    found = self.search_tag(markup)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1626, in search_tag
    if not self._matches(attr_value, match_against):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1696, in _matches
    if isinstance(markup, Tag):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

EDIT 2:

Example website for which script doesn't work: miniusa.com

Comment: Can you add the traceback that is printed when you interrupt?

Comment: Will edit main post in 20sec

Comment: Example of website for which it's stuck: miniusa.com